# Keras : Partial Backpropagation for encoder

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, backpropagation, recommendation-engine

#### Overview

Hi, I'm currently trying to build an Auto-Encoder recommender system model using **keras** (I'm not confident using Tensorflow), currently stuck cause **I can't get keras to do partial back-propagation. (Please help with code if possible or examples from other sources)**.

#### How AutoEnc RecSys work

The idea of the system is to feed high dimension rating data (4k+ feature) with a bunch of zeros ('not reviewed yet') to the encoder, and then decode it back into the original dimension. The previously zero input will be changed to some number and this number act as the prediction result.

#### The problem is

When you feed a bunch of zeros to the encoder, the encoder will learn to output a lot of zeros as well as output (*they think input 0's is the target output, which is not the expected result*) (0 means unpredicted / not rated).

Therefore, the first thing to do is to **mask** the Loss function to **only calculate loss (RMS) from the input that's not zero**. (i.e. use only non zero feature for feed-forward on every train).

Then comes the real problem...
After getting the loss, backprop will occur, and **keras seems to do backpropagation to all of the weight** which some of them (the zeros) should be ignored (to avoid the encoder learn to output zeros)
(loss is shared among all weight on a layer, they calculate gradient based on same loss)

## Is there any way to prevent keras doing back-prop on the weights that was input by zeros ?

### Similar to dropout, but this is not random, instead turn off node/weight if the input for that node is zero)

I've tried to search bunch pages, mostly done by using Tensorflow and make a custom gradient function. Some other propose to simply use mask since zero loss = zero gradients = no backpropagation, but this only work for single number prediction, meanwhile my system will return high-dimension data (same dimension as the input).

note: Custom loss function doesn't work for backpropagation, loss is shared, and some of them still need loss to adjust the weights. I already mask the loss function, so only non-zeros feature will contribute to the loss function. (correct approach, but incomplete)

Some details:
AutoEncoder Architechture : https://prnt.sc/ntzmbf

My Model :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(4000,)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Dense(4000, activation="softmax"))
```

Custom Loss function (masked)

```
import keras.backend as K

# Custom MSE (only calculate loss from non-masked value)
def masked_mse(mask_value):

    def f(y_true, y_pred):
        mask_true = K.cast(K.not_equal(y_true, mask_value), K.floatx())
        masked_squared_error = K.square(mask_true * (y_true - y_pred))
        masked_mse = K.sum(masked_squared_error, axis=-1) / K.sum(mask_true, axis=-1)
        return masked_mse

    f.__name__ = 'Masked MSE (mask_value={})'.format(mask_value)
    return f
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=masked_mse(0))
```

```
model.fit(X_train.values, X_train.values,
          validation_data=(X_val.values, X_val.values),
          epochs=100,
          batch_size=128,
          verbose=1,
          )
```

```
Input example :   [3, 0,   0, 0,   1, 0, ..., 2, 1]
Expected output : [3, 0.1, 2, 0.3, 1, 1, ..., 2, 1]
```

THANK YOU :)